# Code Coverage Instrumentation with different development and automation projects

Tags: java, node.js, code-coverage, automation-testing

`Problem Statement`

> Development project: nodejs
> unit tests: available

> Automation project: java

`Problem`: for our development project we already have unit test coverage. But to figure out automation coverage, we require a medium of instrumenting nodejs code (deployed on some env) while running autotests.

`Need hints on how to achieve same?` Have worked already on jacoco with both development and automation codes in java. Jacoco instruments flow while code is deployed and helps in providing various dump mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Use a code coverage tool for Node.js such as Istanbul, NYC or Jest to instrument the code and collect coverage information during test runs.

Export the coverage data in a format that can be used by other tools for analysis and reporting.

Integrate the coverage data with your existing Jacoco tool to have a unified coverage report for both development and automation projects.